# The % function in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on the exercises in Learning Python the Hard Way and I am wondering what the % function does. I am getting the wrong answer when i count my eggs and hoping understanding this will help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant part of the exercise? not everyone is familiar with LPTHW.

Answer (score 11):

1. I can't really tell why your code is broken because you haven't shown anybody what your code **is**. Please post samples and links next time.
2. Python `%` is used in two places, one is mathematical (the `modulo` operator), and the other has to do with formatting text. I'm going to assume "counting eggs" means the math way.
3. The modulo operator in `X % Y` means "Divide X by Y and give me the remainder." So:

   10 % 2 == 0
   10 % 3 == 1
   10 % 11 == 10

Answer (score 2):

That is the [the modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)